# Why do we test if lo < hi in quicksort algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

The algorithm is as follows:

```
sort(A)
  quicksort(A, 0, n-1)
end

quicksort(A, lo, hi)
  if lo < hi then
    pi = partition(A, lo, hi)
    quicksort(A, lo, pi-1)
    quicksort(A, pi+1, hi)
end
```

My question is, why is it a prerequisite that lo < hi?

Comment: If `lo >= hi`, then what range should be sorted?

Comment: Without the `lo < hi` test, then each call to `quicksort` would unconditionally create two more calls to `quicksort`, and it would run forever (well, until you run out of stack for your recursive calls).  You need a stopping condition.

Comment: Do you understand what `lo` and `hi` do here as parameters?

Comment: Oh, silly me... of course!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every recursive function needs a *base case*: one or more (sets of) parameter values for which an answer can be returned directly instead of recursing again. Without that, the recursion would just go on infinitely (or in practice, until you run out of stack memory - try removing the `if` statement and see what happens). In the quicksort case, the base case is when you are trying to sort a range of numbers that is either empty or only contains one number, in which case you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Not just an empty range of numbers, but a range of length 1 doesn't need sorting either. That's why it's `lo < hi` rather than `lo <= hi`.

Comment: ya this is the answer: the base case is when `lo-hi`